# matplotlib built-in styles all display white background

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

all. New to python and programming in general, and am having issues with matplotlib's built-in styles. Namely, no matter what style I choose the figure background always appears white. Here is the code I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_values = list(range(1,6))
squares = [i**2 for i in range(1,6)]

plt.style.use('seaborn')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(input_values, squares, linewidth=3)

ax.set_title("Square Numbers", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("Value", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Square of Values", fontsize=14)

ax.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=14)

plt.show()
```

and this is what I receive: [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM7gw.png)

When the display first comes up I can briefly see the background in the correct style, but then within a  second it fades to white.

I using Anaconda (python v. 3.8.3) and have tried running from both Sublime Text 3 and the terminal (Git Bash) if that is worth anything.

Edit: Opening the image on my phone does display the correct style, but for whatever reason it does not appear when opening the image on my computer.

Comment: Your figure output looks right to me in the `seaborn` format. Do you expect something else ?

Comment: @JayPatel I added an edit, but it appears to be an issue with the way my computer displays the figure. If I save the figure and view it on another device it does appear to be styled as expected.

Comment: It looks like your monitor `brightness` is too high. try lowering it and see if that works.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is there something wrong with the [the image you attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM7gw.png)? Or are you saying that image is correct but it looks different on your computer? If the latter, it sounds like we'd need a camera shot of your screen to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this was just an issue with my monitors display settings, and adjusting the brightness and contrast corrected the issue!